# rails/carrierwave : nil values saved after upload image by carrierwave, minimagick

Tags: carrierwave, null, minimagick

I'm trying to upload images through carrier wave, and using rails.

using minimagick.

Actually, the uploads working properly I think, but images are not shown up.
Also it shows `nil` value in database.

here's my code.

1. app/models/user.rb

> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> > mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
>
> end

2. mypage.html.erb (form action to "edit_complete")

`<input type="file" name='image'>`

3. users_controller.rb

> def edit_complete
>
> > user = User.find(session[:user_id])
> >
> > user.image = params[:image]
> >
> > user.save
> >
> > redirect_to :back
>
> end

4. app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb

> class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
>
> > include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
> >
> > storage :file
> >
> > def store_dir
> >
> > "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
> >
> > end
>
> end

No errors appeared, but nothing saved in database.

I expect image files should be saved in `public/upload` folder, and image file should be shown in database in `rails c` `User.all`.

However,  when I upload 1.png file,
there are nothing saved, and public/upload folder is not generated. 
Also in database shows `nil` value.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

In file upload You need to use multipart option in form tag ie multipart option should be true in form tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
   <%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
        <%= f.file_field :image%>
        <%= f.submit 'Edit'%>
    <% end %>
```